# USB driver errors in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, android, adb

I have been facing the issue of frequent connect/disconnect of my Android device when connected with USB to my computer running Ubuntu16.04.

I have seen similar questions on different portals complaining same on this ubuntu version, but none of them have any resolution or specific reason for this issue.

Please note that I did not have this problem with same devices when I had Ubuntu14.04 version.

Below is the snippet of dmesg:

```
[16166.655958] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 58
[16166.855924] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 59 using ehci-pci
[16167.315966] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 60 using ehci-pci
[16167.429134] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee7
[16167.429136] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[16167.429138] usb 1-1.3: Product: Android
[16167.429139] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: USB Developer
[16167.429139] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 20080411
[16196.483655] usb 1-1.3: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd adb rqt 128 rq 6 len 256 ret -71
[16196.609244] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 60
[16196.808447] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 61 using ehci-pci
[16197.268418] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 62 using ehci-pci
[16197.382180] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee7
[16197.382183] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[16197.382184] usb 1-1.3: Product: Android
[16197.382185] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: USB Developer
```

I have already tried different USB ports on my machine, different devices and cables too to rule out any issues specific to them. I had tried changing USB modes too in Developer Options on my Android devices but in some time, I get this issue with all of those modes.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.